# In a QT C++ based GUI,all tr() which aren't prefixed with QObject doesn't work

Tags: qt, translation

in a QT(C++) based GUI,all .hpp files have been marked with Macro Q_OBJECT,corresponded .cpp files have many tr("keys to translate"),and these lines has been put in CMakeLists.txt

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE SRC_FILES CONFIGURE_DEPENDS "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp" "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/shonDyCommon/*.cpp")
file(GLOB_RECURSE UI_FILES "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.ui")
file(GLOB_RECURSE HEADER_FILES CONFIGURE_DEPENDS "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.hpp" "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.h" "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/shonDyCommon/*.hpp")

set(TRANS_QRC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/trans_resources.qrc)
configure_file(
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/resource/trans_resources.qrc.in
        ${TRANS_QRC}
        COPYONLY
)
set(TS_FILES
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/resource/translate/shonDy_zh_CN.ts
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/resource/translate/shonDy_en_US.ts
        )
set_source_files_properties(${TS_FILES} PROPERTIES OUTPUT_LOCATION ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR})
qt5_create_translation(QM_FILES ${TS_FILES} ${SRC_FILES} ${UI_FILES} ${HEADER_FILES})

qt5_add_big_resources(GUI_RESOURCES "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/resource/resources.qrc")
```

All keys got generated in .ts file after compilation,no matter it comes from .ui file or .cpp file.

When GUI opened,all keys which come from .ui files or QObject:tr("") got translated correctly,but all keys come from .cpp with tr("") which are not prefixed with QObject:: don't got translated.

If picking any tr("specificKey") in a .cpp,prefixing it like this: QObject::tr("specificKey"),recompiling without any extra efforts,and open it again,this key got translated correctly.

Question is:

Why don't the keys in .cpp got translated?